# Magento 2.2.5: Error on cron:run after every production deployment

Tags: magento2, cron, composer, magento-2.2.5

Since we upgraded Magento to 2.2.5, after every deployment to production (which includes `git pull...`, `composer update` & all other relevant Magento CLI commands for production deployment), our indexers stops to work & when we check the cron by running `php bin/magento cron:run` we get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Lock\LockManagerInterface in /.../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory

The only way we found that seems to solve this (temporarily) is to clear the composer cache, remove the `vendor` dir, running `composer update` again & re-deploying Magento again.
We have to do that every time, after every deployment & it's really annoying.

Comment: did you got any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. We are still doing what I mentioned on the last paragraph...

Comment: Having the same issue... Your workaround does not work for us.  What version of PHP are you using? Have you seen: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16793 Do you have Wyomind Cron Scheduler in your build?

Comment: PHP 7.0.30 & yes, we have Wyomind Cron Scheduler.

Comment: I've spent time removing Wyomind Cron Scheduler and in fact all Wyomind extension. I still have the error... I have also disabled all third party extensions, error still persists.

Comment: @Flipmedia I don't have Wyomind extension installed, still having this error, it was working few days ago but now it doesn't. Let me know if you get any solution.

Comment: @Piyush Please add report to github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16793

Answer (score 2):

Your di.xml is stale / not upgraded correctly, see the below grep result, if you do not get this result from you di.xml file is the issue.

```
$grep Lock app/etc/di.xml 
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Lock\LockManagerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Lock\Backend\Database" />
```

In our case I found that our deployment script was excluding di.xml from being rolled out to production. I removed this exclusion and redeployed to correct the issue.

You may find that permissions / user / group allocated to di.xml stopped the file being updated...

See solution here with correct di.xml supplied: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16793#issuecomment-418334379

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cache, and generated files, and then retry running your commands.

```
rm -rf var/cache/ generated/
```